# Customize or remove space between ion row

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am learning Ionic app. I got introduced to Grid thing, however, I am stuck at removing/modifying spaces between rows ( row number 2 and 3) as shown in the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I have following code in my HTML:

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-row>     
      <ion-label> I am good I do not want any space.</ion-label>
    </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <div >
      <div class="inner">
        <ion-label *ngIf="!inverse"  no-margin>1 USD = 67 INR</ion-label>
        <ion-label *ngIf="inverse" no-margin>1 INR = {{(1/67) | number }} USD </ion-label>
      </div>
      <button (click)="inverse=!inverse" ion-button clear class="iconWidth" color="dark">  <ion-icon name="swap" class="rotate"></ion-icon></button>
    </div>
  </ion-row>
<ion-row>
  <p>Can you help me to get rid of space between this row and above</p>
  <ion-label> Thanks</ion-label>
</ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

SCSS:

```
page-home {

  .rotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

  .inner{
    display: inline-block;
    width:70%;

    }
  .iconWidth{
    width:20%;
    }

}
```

How can I customize the gap between row 2 and row 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use negative `margin-top`

**html**

```
<ion-row class="bottomRow">
  <p>Can you help me to get rid of space between this row and above</p>
```

**scss**

```
 .bottomRow
{
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-6h89bg?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.scss)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was going into the tag, linking it with `class="foo"` and then setting `.foo{padding:0px}`

Answer (score -1):

try using `no-padding` and `no-margin` like this and on others you want off

```
  <ion-row no-padding>
  <p no-margin>Can you help me to get rid of space between this row and above</p>
  <ion-label> Thanks</ion-label>
```

or

```
 .inner{
  display: inline-block;
  width:70%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;

    }
```